# Does the integral of a nonconstant monomial over the unit disk vanish?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I've been thinking recently about integrals over fixed domains and what they do to monomials.

Let $[\varphi]$ be an Iverson bracket, sending true to 1 and false to 0. Let $a \equiv_{(n)} b$ mean that $a$ is equivalent to $b$ mod $n$.

The unit interval has a nice formula.

$$ \int_0^1 x^n \text{d}x = \frac{1}{n+1} $$

The interval $[-1, 1]$ also has a nice formula, in particular the odd terms drop out, leaving only the even terms.

$$ \int_{-1}^1 x^n \text{d}x = [n \equiv_{(2)} 1] \frac{2}{n+1} $$

However, the interval $[-1,1]$ is kind of a cross section of the complex unit disk. That got me thinking about what non-constant monomials look like on the unit disk ... and I think the graph of $\text{Re}(z^n)$ can always be rotated a little bit to look like the graph of $\text{Re}(-z^n)$ for positive $n$, but I'm not sure.

I think we can make this argument rigorous by "pairing up" every $z$ with $u_{2n}z$ with $u_{2n}$ being the root of unity with least positive $\theta$ in the polar representation. $(u_{2n})^nz^n$ would then equal $-1z^n$.

I'm not sure exactly which complex integral to use, and [contour integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration) seem to apply to the wrong kind of object, so I'm expressing it as two independent real integrals over the real and pure imaginary axes.

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} [a^2+b^2 < 1] (a+bi)^n \;\text{d}a\text{d}b = 0 \;\; \text{when $n \ge 1$} $$

Is this true?

Comment: In other words you are looking for $\iint_D (a+bi)^n \ da \ db$ where $D$ is the unit disk?

Comment: @gt6989b yes. The Iverson bracket will prevent the extraneous material in the corners of $[-1,1] \times [-1, 1]$ from influencing the value of the integral.

Comment: See my answer. The term *Iverson bracket* is new for me, we used to call this an indicator function in analysis...

Comment: It is just an indicator function. I use it a lot in sums and integrals instead of explicitly removing things from the domain of integration. The Iverson bracket is the name for the notation using $[...]$, is there a more standard syntax for turning arbitrary propositions into indicator functions?

Comment: We used to use $\mathbb{I}_{A}$ or $I(A)$ as an indicator of the event $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\iint_D (a+bi)^n dadb
 = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \left(re^{it}\right)^n rdrdt
 = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{itn}dt \int_0^1 r^{n+1} dr
$$
and the left integral is zero since $e^{2\pi i} = 1$.

This also would follow from the Cauchy Theorem since $z^n$ is analytic in the disk.

Comment: You want $(re^{it})^n$ in the integral.

Comment: @zhw. +1, thanks for the good eye, corrected